# I won't be applying for master's programs until next year. Should I start studying for the GRE now?

Tags: masters, gre, preparation

I'm an undergraduate in mathematics, and won't be finishing my Bachelor's degree until next Spring or next Fall (2016). I plan on applying for a master's program before possibly moving onto a PhD (if I like the research) after I get my bachelor's.

Should I start studying GRE-type material now, even if just in my free time, to hopefully have a bit more of an intimate knowledge of the kinds of questions it will ask, as well as really solidify my problem solving in those areas? Or is that overkill?

Comment: Yes, the sooner the better

Comment: It would at least be worth looking at some sample questions and taking a practice test.  This will give you some idea of what you should study and how much over the next year.

Comment: The general test? Or the subject test?

Comment: @AruRay, whichever is required for most master's admissions :-)

Comment: Hard to know how to advise you, since we random strangers on the internet don't know whether you'll have a hard time with the GREs or even whether the places you apply will even want them (my university didn't).

Comment: Which university is that? Isn't it more common than not that master's programs want GRE scores?

Comment: Most graduate programs will require the GRE General test; as a math major you should find the (math portion of the) general test quite easy - in my opinion this is not worth studying for too much ahead of time (I studied for maybe a day at best), depending on how good a test taker you are. The GRE subject test *might* be required for a masters program - in general the more competitive programs will require it. This is definitely worth preparing for ahead of time.

Comment: One thing to note is that I think the 2005 (?) exam was *incredibly* easy. ETS has made that exam available for download to practice on. I think I got an 800 on it when I took it as a practice test. More recent exams have been rather more difficult. When I officially took the MGRE, I got about a 700 and I studied pretty well. The problem is that they asked questions that they'd never even hinted at asking (like some really annoyingly complicated planar geometry questions and rather complicated topology questions).

Answer (score 2):

First, the GRE, especially the subject test in math, is a very highly stylized version of a very particular slice of a fairly low-level piece of school-mathematics... Whatever one thinks about it, it is widely used, and its idiosyncrasies and limitations are often over-looked for the sake of the convenience of having a single number to (supposedly usefully) compare people from very different backgrounds. Thus, you don't want to show up and be surprised by what it is, for sure! As in comments, do some practice exams to see what the questions are...

Also, *do* think in terms of the possibilities for "gaming" a multiple-choice exam. The most successful of your competitors will have some success with that aspect, apart from knowing or not-knowing mathematics.

But do *not* let the GRE too-much affect studying actual mathematics. For example, things that don't admit "testing" by multiple-choice questions can't make it onto the GRE, yet arguably are far more important in the larger enterprise than things that *can*.

The possibility of gaming the exam also means that "problem solving" is not really what it's about. It's about doing enough diagnostic stuff to eliminate wrong choices, and then whatever's left has to be right. This is methodologically wildly different from the practice of mathematics.

Comment: When you say the subject test, do you mean the math part of the general test? Because my understanding is that the math GRE is quite advanced.